# When do I stop reading from a file?

Tags: c++, stl, flags, ifstream, eof

Does `some_file.good()` return `false` after reading the last entry from the file, or after attempting to read beyond that? That is, should I write

```
while (input.good())
{
    getline(input, line);
    // ...process
}
```

or

```
getline(input, line);
while (input.good())
{
    // ...process
    getline(input, line);
}
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Attempting to read beyond that...

You could try:

```
while(getline(input, line))
{
// do stuff with line
}
```

Should add, that stream implements `operator!`, which checks the flags that you normally would. The return from `getline` is the input stream, but because of the operator, the flags are checked.

Comment: Ah, didn't know `getline` echoes the input stream back to the caller. In that case, I think I'm gonna go with `while (getline(input, line).good())` for readability's sake.

Comment: Actually, it's quite idiomatic, so you won't need it for readability. `while (stream >> item)` is also idiomatic (but doesn't work for lines out of the box ;))

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, getline returns zero when there are no more lines. Also the method `eof()` returns true if the EOF flag is set (i.e. end of file reached on the stream):

```
if(input.eof())
{
// end of file
}
```

Comment: `getline` does not return zero, ever. It returns the input stream.